# Serializar y deserializar objetos y propiedades en Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Tengo un problema con la serialización y deserialización de objetos en Java, y creo que es porque realmente no entiendo como funciona. Mi programa consiste en unas hojas de calculo como en Excel, pero por consola. Tengo una clase "Book" y una clase "Page":

En Book, tengo declarado un HashMap de Page y en Page tengo un Hashmap de String (para simular las celdas). Ahora quiero que ese libro sea persistente y para ello lo que hago es serializar el objeto libro (instancia de Book)

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOut =
    new FileOutputStream("H:\\Users\\thero\\Desktop\\bin\\libro.bin");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(libro);
    out.close();
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.printf("Se ha guardado el libro correctamente");
}catch (IOException i) {
     i.printStackTrace();
}
```

Este codigo esta metido dentro de un metodo de una clase llamada "Salvar" que llamo desde el main.
Paralelamente tengo una clase "Cargar" con el metodo contrario:

```
try {
     FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("H:\\Users\\thero\\Desktop\\bin\\libro.bin");
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
     libro = (Book) in.readObject();
     in.close();
     fileIn.close();
} catch (IOException i) {
     i.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(Cargar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Este metodo tambien lo llamo desde el main, y al ejecutarlo, no salta ninguna excepción. Sin embargo parece ser que solo carga la instancia de Book, pero no carga la propiedad Hashmap, y por tanto no cargan las hojas creadas ni las celdas ni nada. Donde puede estar el problema? Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo, la serializacion consiste en convertir un objeto o conjunto de estos en bits para tratarlos en diferentes usos informaticos, sea para almacenarlos en archivos, o enviarlos mediante sockets (De groso modo, por la red). Puedes serializar cualquier objeto, siempre y cuando sea heredado de la interfaz `Serializable`.

La ventaja de `HashMap` es que ya tiene como interface implementada `Serializable`, por lo que nosotros podemos serializar todo el HashMap de una vez, con todos sus datos y atributos internos, por lo que al abrir el programa, solo es abrir el flujo, leer y asignar, cerrar los flujos y el buffer y listo.

Un ejemplo en codigo Java es el siguiente:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Persona> personas = new HashMap<Integer, Persona>();
```

Tenemos un `HashMap`, el cual la llave primaria sera de la clase `Integer` o entero, y el contenido sera de la clase `Persona`. Para guardar puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
public boolean add(int edad, String nombre){
        Persona p = new Persona(edad, nombre);
        return personas.put(personas.size()+1, p) != null;
}
```

Hasta aquí solo guarda en memoria, para guardar en el archivo haz lo siguiente:

```
    public void guardar(){
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(this.personas);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

El método add y guardar los puedes fusionar si quieres. Toda la clase donde esta toda la serializacion esta de la siguiente forma:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Carlos
 */
public class Gestion {
    private HashMap<Integer, Persona> personas = new HashMap<Integer, Persona>();
    private File file;
    private FileInputStream fis;
    private FileOutputStream fos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;

    public Gestion(String ruta) {
        this.file = new File(ruta);
        this.crearArchivo();
    }
    public boolean add(int edad, String nombre){
        Persona p = new Persona(edad, nombre);
        return personas.put(personas.size()+1, p) != null;
    }

    public HashMap<Integer, Persona> obtenerTodo() {
        try {
            HashMap<Integer, Persona> personasTemp = new HashMap<>();
            boolean buffer = false;
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            while (fis.available() > 0) {
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                Persona p = (Persona) ois.readObject();
                if (p != null) {
                    personasTemp.put(personasTemp.size() + 1, p);
                }
                buffer = true;
            }
            if (buffer) {
                ois.close();
            }
            fis.close();
            return personasTemp;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void obtener(){
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            boolean buffer = false;
            while(fis.available() > 0){
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                HashMap<Integer, Persona> personasTemp = (HashMap<Integer, Persona>) ois.readObject();
                if (personasTemp != null){
                    this.personas = personasTemp;
                }
                buffer = true;
            }
            if (buffer){
                ois.close();
            }
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void guardar(){
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(this.personas);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void crearArchivo() {
        if(!this.file.exists()){
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Gestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void imprimirTodo(){
        if(this.personas.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("No hay nada...");
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < this.personas.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(personas.get(i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

La clase personas es la siguiente:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Carlos
 */
public class Persona implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int edad;
    private String nombre;

    public Persona(int edad, String nombre) {
        this.edad = edad;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 59 * hash + this.edad;
        hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.nombre);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Persona other = (Persona) obj;
        if (this.edad != other.edad) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.nombre, other.nombre)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persona{" + "edad=" + edad + ", nombre=" + nombre + '}';
    }



}
```

Y finalmente la clase Main o principal, que es donde esta el Main, es la siguiente:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Carlos
 */
public class Main {
    private final Gestion gestion;
    public Main() {
        this.gestion = new Gestion("ejemplo.bin");
        /*this.gestion.add(25, "Carlos");
        this.gestion.add(20, "Juan");
        this.gestion.add(19, "Pepe");
        this.gestion.guardar();*/
        this.gestion.imprimirTodo();
        this.gestion.obtener();
        this.gestion.imprimirTodo();
    }



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }

}
```